# How to style the last element with a certain class in a nested list with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, omeka

I need to style the last HTML element with a certain css class, but I must consider certain constraints.

In the website I'm working on the navigation menu is made by several nested lists, when one element is clicked on the `li` element with the page name acquires the .active class, if it belongs to a nested list all parent `li` elements above also acquire the `.active` class.

I'd like to be able to style the last `li` element with class `.active` since it corresponds to the currently open webpage.

The disposition of the element of the lists can take any disposition so I need something that works with different indentations or number of elements.

I'm working with Omeka s content management system, which means that I can't use javascript or modify the HTML files, so I'm looking for a solution in pure CSS.

here is an example of the menu structure:

```
<ul class="">
<li >
     <a href="">Introduction</a>
</li>
     <li>
          <a href="">level 1</a>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="">subpage</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li>
                           <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
                           <ul>
                               <li>
                                   <a href="">sub-sub-subpage-a</a>
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <a href="">sub-sub-subpage-b</a>
                               </li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
</ul>
```

here is when I'm on th page "sub-sub-page-b":

```
<ul class="">
<li >
     <a href="">Introduction</a>
</li>
     <li class="active">
          <a href="">level 1</a>
           <ul>
               <li class="active">
                   <a href="">subpage</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li class="active">
                           <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
                           <ul>
                               <li>
                                   <a href="">sub-sub-subpage-a</a>
                               </li>
                               <li class="active">
                                   <a href="">sub-sub-subpage-b</a>
                               </li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried to use `li.active:last-of-type` but it only select the last element of type `li`

I also tried to use:

```
 
.active > a:only-child{
 color: red 
}
```

but it only works if the element I want to select is an only child.

Comment: Note that :last-of-type only applies to elements with the same direct parent (siblings), so even if it worked with classnames it wouldn't solve your issue.

Comment: Have you tried :last-child?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a certain way by using the CSS :has but note this is behind a flag on Firefox at the moment.

```css
li.active:not(:has(ul li.active))>a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="">
  <li>
    <a href="">Introduction</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="">level 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="">subpage</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="active">
            <a href="">sub-subpage</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">sub-sub-subpage-a</a>
              </li>
              <li class="active">
                <a href="">sub-sub-subpage-b</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```